# DragonMake iOS-simulator error when trying to build

Tags: theos, cydia, cydia-substrate

I'm working on a very simple Tweak on DragonMake. So far I'm getting the following errors when building:

`ld: building for 'iOS', but linking in dylib (/Users/[myuser]/.dragon/frameworks/CydiaSubstrate.framework/CydiaSubstrate.tbd) built for 'iOS-simulator' clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

I reverted to basically an empty project to narrow down the problem, so here's my DragonMake file:

`name: Testing id: com.serch.testing depends: mobilesubstrate architecture: iphoneos-arm version: '0.1' description: Testing tweak build author: Serch section: Tweaks`

I'm working on MacOS Sonoma with the latest Dragon V 2.0.0. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, I had to edit my CydiaSubstrate.tbd file inside CydiaSubstrate.framework

From

```
archs: [ armv7, armv7s, arm64, arm64e, i386, x86_64 ]
```

To

```
archs: [ armv7, armv7s, arm64, arm64e ]
```